# left side navigation bar in jsp not working properly

Tags: html, css

i'm getting expended menu bar with subitems when i run my jsp file and even it is not collapsing on click mean no response from the menu bar i already tried different ways to resolve this issue but unable to resolve.

> HTML

```
<link
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="menu-list">

        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>
                    Home
            </a></li>

            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products"
                class="collapsed active"><a><i
                    class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                <li><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                <a><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span
                    class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                <li>New Service 1</li>
                <li>New Service 2</li>
                <li>New Service 3</li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                <a><i class="fa fa-bus fa-lg"></i> New <span
                    class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
                <li>New New 1</li>
                <li>New New 2</li>
                <li>New New 3</li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
            </a></li>

            <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css for nav

> CSS

```
.nav-side-menu {
overflow: auto;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 200;
background-color: #2e353d;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 24%;
height: 100%;
color: #e1ffff;
}

.nav-side-menu .brand {
background-color: #23282e;
line-height: 50px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
display: none;
}

.nav-side-menu ul, .nav-side-menu li {
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 35px;
cursor: pointer;

}

.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before, .nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before
{
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f078";
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .active, .nav-side-menu li .active {
border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
background-color: #4f5b69;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active, .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active
{
color: #d19b3d;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a, .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a
{
color: #d19b3d;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li, .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
background-color: #181c20;
border: none;
line-height: 28px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
margin-left: 0px;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover, .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover
{
background-color: #020203;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before, .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before
{
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f105";
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
padding-left: 0px;
border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
 }

.nav-side-menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #e1ffff;
 }

.nav-side-menu li a i {
padding-left: 10px;
width: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-side-menu li:hover {
border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
background-color: #4f5b69;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

 @media ( max-width : 767px) {
.nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
}
}

 @media ( min-width : 767px) {
.nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
}
}

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

please leave your valuable answer and comments.

Comment: Post if you find any errors in your browser console.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan  no error

Comment: Can you help me reproduce error in `https://jsfiddle.net/` by add your code and share the path?

Comment: Btw this question is no where related to jsp, so I'm removing tag and see your code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/g6v741f6/1/). Edit the fiddle and reproduce your error.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan  https://jsfiddle.net/Tom_williams/ob0mexLh/ this is the link please check

Comment: Just update my css and html

Comment: @VinothKrishnan   can you please help me with this coz i'm new to css and html and don't know much about designing part may be the issue is silly but for me its hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's correct workaround for your issue, I have added jQuery function to enable the toggle. Let me know if this helps.

```
$(".collapsed").click(function(){
    $($(this).data("target")).toggle('slow');
});
```

Please find the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/ob0mexLh/1/) for demo.

Comment: Did you added jQuery plugin? Just check the updated [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/ob0mexLh/2/).